# Django cannot serialize regex.Regex - What to do?

Tags: python, django, serialization

Apps used:

- Django 1.10.5
- regex 2017.1.17 (https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex)

I'm using this regex as validator in my model:
`regex.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$')`

I get this Error running `manage.py makemigrations`:

`ValueError: Cannot serialize: regex.Regex('^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4}$', flags=regex.V0)`

Now I don't know what I have to do for `regex.compile` is not just a class (I could subclass). In the Django code I found this:

[`COMPILED_REGEX_TYPE = type(re.compile(''))`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/migrations/utils.py)

This is how Django detects regex that are compiled with Python's standard `re` concerning serialisation.

What is the best practice to deal with it?

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but have you tried adding `COMPILED_REGEX_TYPE = type(regex.compile(''))` to your settings.py file?

Comment: You could put the regex in a validation function. That should be serializable. Or just use the basic regexvalidator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/validators/#regexvalidator

Comment: what does `{2-4}` mean in your regex?  Should it be `{2,4}`?

Comment: @JaredGoguen 
That doesn't work. 
@HåkenLid 
This function method seems to be the solution. Yes, I meant `{2,4}`.